# Upload album to facebook from another website

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Assume that I have know about FB API, I just want to ask "any way to upload album to FB from my website?".

Ex: xkcn.info/archive is my website, I develop a checkbox function that allow user can mark pictures and upload to facebook, it create an album or photo...;).

Thank a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes of course it is possible.

1. First of all you need the permissions:

   `user_photos` to get the access to the user's album

   `publish_stream` to post photos to an album
2. You can create an empty album of a page by issuing an `HTTP Post` request to `me/albums` with following parameters:

   *name*-         The name of the album

   *message*-   The description of the album

   In return you will get the `album_id` which you can use to post photos into
3. You can add photos to an album by issuing an `HTTP POST` request to `ALBUM_ID/photos` with following parameters:

   *source*- Photo content   (multipart/form-data)

   *message*-    Photo description   string

Reference: [Album](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/album/)

Comment: Wow, Thank you so much, let's me try :-)